# Building a Caesar Cipher Decoder in C

Tags: c

I'm new to C and this was a bonus question for an assignment that came and went but I'm still trying to puzzle through it.

The aim is to accept input from a file that is encoded with the Caesar Cipher (move letters left or right in alphabet), figure out which letter has the highest frequency then use this to guess the shifting value and decode the input.

I separately managed to read the frequency and calculate the shifting value, and then decode the input using the result from this. But I can't make it work when I put everything back together in one file.
In fact it doesn't even look like it is doing anything right now besides going through main and printing Success1.

Any suggestions on how to improve this or reasons why it isn't working would be great. I feel like I'm about 90% there but can't figure out that last 10%.

Thanks.

```
int count_freq( int count[] );
int decode( int shift, int ch );
int rotate_right( int ch );
int rotate_left( int ch );

                                                                               // count the number of occurrences of each letter
int count_freq( int count[] )
{
  int ch;
  int shift, maximum, size = 26, c, location = 1, i;

  while(( ch = getchar()) != EOF ) 
    {
        ch = toupper( ch );                                                     // convert to upper case
        if( ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z' ) 
        {
            i = ch - 'A';
            count[i]++;                                                         // increment i'th element
        }
    } 

    maximum = count[26];                                                        //Sets maximum size of count

    for( c = 1; c < size; c++ )
    {
        if( count[c] > maximum )                                                //not 100% sure what is happening here but it works
        {
          maximum = count[c];
          location = c+1;
        }
    }

    shift = 5-(location-1);                                                     //Compares the value of the letter with the highest frequency to E to find the shift
    return(shift);
    printf("shift = %d", shift );
    printf("Success2"); 
}

int decode( int ch, int shift)
{
    int j;
     if( shift >= 0 ) 
    {                                                                           //If shift is greater than zero
           for( j=0; j < shift; j++ )                                           //Start at i=0, increment by one while i is less than shift
           {              
                     ch = rotate_right( ch );                                   //Use the function that increases the characters
           }
    }
    else 
    {                                                                           //For shifting values less than zero      
           for( j=0; j < -shift; j++ )                                          //Start at i=0, increment by one while i is less than negative shift (ie. if shifting value is -10 this goes up to i=10)
           {                 
                     ch = rotate_left( ch );                                    //Use the function that decreases the characters        
           }
    }

    printf("Success3");     
}

int rotate_right( int ch )
{
   if( ch == 'Z' ) {                                                            //If the character is Z then make it A
      return( 'A' );
   }
   else if( ch == 'z' ) {                                                       //Same for lower case
      return( 'a' );
   }
   else if(  ( ch >= 'A' && ch < 'Z' )                                          //If the Character is greater than or equal to A and less than Z, add one to the value of the character. Eg. B -> C
           ||( ch >= 'a' && ch < 'z' )) {
      return( ch + 1 );
   }
   else {                                                                       //This is for the characters that are not letters. Punctuation and spaces
      return( ch );
   }
   printf("Success4");
}

int rotate_left( int ch )                                                       //This is all the same but it shifts the value of the characters the other way. Eg. C -> B                   
{
   if( ch == 'A' ) {
      return( 'Z' );
   }
   else if( ch == 'a' ) {
      return( 'z' );
   }
   else if(  ( ch > 'A' && ch <= 'Z' )
           ||( ch > 'a' && ch <= 'z' )) {
      return( ch - 1 );
   }
   else {
      return( ch );
   }
   printf("Success5");
}

int main( )
{
    int count[26] = { 0 };                                                      //Initialize array elements
    int ch, shift;
    count_freq( count );                                                        //Count frequencies

    while(( ch = getchar()) != EOF )                                            //While the variable ch is not the end of the string entered
    {     
         putchar( decode( ch, shift ));                                         //Calls the decode function from above using ch from getchar and shift from scanf 
    }

    printf("Success1");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the code contains lots of problems.  For instance these lines: `    return(shift);
    printf("shift = %d", shift );
    printf("Success2"); ` means the function is exited at the 'return' statement, so the two printf() statements will never be executed.  The compiler should have told you this:  Always enable all warnings when compiling (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` ) then fix the warnings.    The `decode()` function says it returns an 'int', however there is no 'return value;' statement in that function.  The compiler should have told you this.

Comment: the posted code fails to properly handle punctuation and similar printable characters

Comment: the `rotate_left()` and `rotate_right()` functions could be reduced to (say) 6 lines and a single `return` statement by code that performs modulo on the input character after determining if the character is upper case or lower case (try using `isupper()` and `islower()` from `ctypes.h`)   Generally, it is very bad programming practice to have more than one `return` statement in a function.

Comment: the biggest problem in the code is the function: `decode()` is not returning the decoded character, via a `return` statement

Comment: in C, arrays are indexed starting from 0 not 1, so this line: `maximum = count[26]; ` is accessing 1 byte past the end of the count[] array.  This is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: using 'getchar()` means the input is being typed in by the user, rather than coming from a file.  AND the user will have to type in the same sequence twice.  Suggest passing in the name of a file, have main() open that file for input, pass the file descriptor to `count_freq()`,  then calling fseek() to get back to the beginning of the file for the actual calls to decode.  suggest reading the characters from the file using `fgetc()`

Comment: given these two related lines: `          location = c+1;
    shift = 5-(location-1);`  Where did the '-5' come from?  the location is only an offset into the `count[]` array.   and the `count[]` array is only the frequency, not the actual char offset.   The code needs modification to get the actual offset, (which happens to be `location`, if setting `location = c;` rather than `location = c+1;`  In general, location (without that unsupported '-5' is the shift amount.

Comment: there are some 'magic' numbers in the code, For instance `26`.  that value is used in several places in the code.  using 'magic' numbers makes code much harder to understand and a real headache to maintain.  strongly suggest using an enum of #define, with meaningful names, for the value 26, then using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Comment: when `shift` is properly calculated, then the value will be in the range 0...25, never <0.

Comment: IF the `-5` is making the assumption that the character 'e' will be the most common character (given a large enough sample of input) then you could make the argument that it is needed in the calculation.   then the current calculations, including the possibility of a negative shift are reasonable.  However, the code fails to make that detail clear.  And even then, 'e' is only the most common char for english,  so would not work for spanish, french, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments guys. I suppose I should have been a bit more clear in my original question. This program is only for english and is assuming that E is the most used character. Punctuation and the rest is being ignored and I didn't need to retain capitals.

Answer (score 2):

At the very minimum, your code doesn't work because there are no return statements in `decode()`.

If your compiler didn't warn / error on this, you should get a better compiler.

Comment: That is a great point, thanks. I'm using Dev C++ which I had thought was pretty good. Maybe I need to switch to Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

First thing I notice:

You never use intialize `shift` when you call `count_freq()`

So when you pass `shift` to decode it gets passed as a garbage value of whatever is on the stack.

Comment: I.E. this line: `count_freq( count );`  should be: `shift = count_freq( count );`

Comment: `shift` is on the stack, it contains what ever value is at the address of `shift`.  The chances of `shift` being 0 are 1 / 4gig on a 32 bit architecture.  So trash would be passed to the function: `decode()` in the 'shift' parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use modulus operator `%` to shift characters

```
result = 'A' + (c - 'A' + shift) % 26
```

`% 26` ensures no character goes out of range.

If shift is 2 and character is 'A' => result is 'C'

If shift is 2 and character is 'Z' => result is 'B'

To decode the message, change `shift` to `26 - shift`.

```
void rotate(char* msg, int shift)
{
    for (int i = 0, len = strlen(msg); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (msg[i] >= 'a' && msg[i] <= 'z')
            msg[i] = 'a' + (msg[i] - 'a' + shift) % 26;
        else if (msg[i] >= 'A' && msg[i] <= 'Z')
            msg[i] = 'A' + (msg[i] - 'A' + shift) % 26;
    }

    printf("%s\n", msg);
}

void encode(char* msg, int shift)
{
    rotate(msg, shift);
}

void decode(char* msg, int shift)
{
    rotate(msg, 26 - shift);
}

int main()
{
    char message[100];
    strcpy(message, "ABCD XYZ");
    encode(message, 2);
    decode(message, 2);
    return 0;
}
```